# Having a "display: inline-block" as a parent to a "display: grid" element without having text overlap?

Tags: css, css-grid, word-wrap

I'm trying to arrange a set of statistics such that:

- they are displayed on a single horizontal line
- the enclosing element is no wider than it needs to be to contain the content
- there should be a fixed gap between statistics

I tried implementing this using `display: grid`. Here is my approach:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stats {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="stat">
      <strong>Value:</strong> 1,234,568
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
      <strong>Another value:</strong> 98,765
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
      <strong>Test value:</strong> 83,263
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this results in some strange overlapping. Despite there being plenty of room for the `.outer` element to expand, the statistics are wrapped over several lines and the text runs into other columns:

[image]

How can I avoid this problem? I tried adding:

```
.stat {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

...but the text still "runs" together. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem stems from this declaration:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr))
```

You're setting the columns to shrink to zero width.

Also, `1fr` does nothing here, because there is no free space in the container. (You have the primary container set to `inline-block`, i.e., min-width. This means no extra space.)

At a minimum, these commands appear to be confusing the `inline-block` algorithm.

Consider leaving the columns at `auto` width (a default setting).

And, perhaps, setting them to appear in the first row. (I used the `grid-auto-flow: column` technique.)

```css
.outer {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stats {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="stat">
      <strong>Value:</strong> 1,234,568
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
      <strong>Another value:</strong> 98,765
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
      <strong>Test value:</strong> 83,263
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```